# How to select the range of the print area of worksheet?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a worksheet that I manually set the print area of the working area. What I want to do is select the range of the print area and do a spell check.

```
ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Select --> this selects ALL used range that is also not in the print area.
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this:

```
Activesheet.Range(ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea).Select
```

One note, though you asked how to select the range, one should avoid using select whenever possible and just do what you want to do.

```
Activesheet.Range(ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea).CheckSpelling
```